# Bootcamp windows installation not allowing Windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows, disk-utility

Hi I am trying to install windows 10 on my macbook pro 8,2(late 2011), when I open Bootcamp it is having options to create windows 10 installation in usb as seen in image.

[image]

Now, I am able to create the windows 10 install disk sucessfully using the iso, but after that the bootcamp popups the error message as seen in image

[image]

So after reading the message i decided to make windows 7 install disk which not in the list but i tried checking the same windows 10 option and added the iso file of windows 7 then again the bootcamp pops up the the error as seen in image

[image]

As seen it is not allowing me to go in both the cases, if I do the partition manually it is also not seen in startup disks also.

Want to install windows on mac any kind of suggession will be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

it should be possible to install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp. Apple has a rather [lengthy KB article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) on exactly how you should proceed.

Comment: my bootcamp version is 6, when i check at last option that is windows 10 install is says only windows  7 is supported by this mac but doesnot provide any option to create windows 7 install disk.